# SDL Mix_Chunk alen does not tally with original file size

Tags: c, audio, sdl

We are trying to process audio via `SDL_Mixer` using the chunks. But what we notice is that when we get this values of the alen of the chunks are does not tally with actual file size. Any reason for it ? The alen is referring to `test1->alen;` where test1 is `Mix_Chunk *test1` .

Comment: I would edit this but I haven't got a clue what any of this means. I assume you meant to write "SDL chunk alen does not..."?

Comment: YEs I mean why both the real file size and test1->alen; does not match